# Get maximum number of items recorded in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a Mysql table called "roomrent" which have following structure:

```
Id     city           country
----------------------------------
1      Dhaka          Bangladesh
2      Dhaka          Bangladesh
3      Washington     United States 
4      Paris          France
5      Dhaka          Bangladesh
6      Paris          France
```

I want to show 5 cities from DB which are recorded maximum time. Like: in this table **Dhaka** is recoded maximum time.

So it's should be show like this:

```
Dhaka
Paris
Washington
and other.....
```

How do i get this with mysql query ? I know it's can be done by mysql **Select query**,  But I can't.

Note: I'm new in php & mysql and It's my learning time.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT city FROM roomrent LIMIT 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the following. Which gets a count of the cities that appear in your table and will return the top 5:

```
select city, count(city) Total
from roomrent
group by city
order by total desc
limit 0, 5
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c935f/1)

Comment: Thanks @bluefeet I'm using it

Comment: One question why you use "Total" ?

Comment: @BabuAhmed The `total` is the alias for the `count(city)` column. I am using that so I can apply an `order by` that column in descending order. Then you will return the 5 rows with the highest number of times it appears in the table. :)